# ear-javaee6 archetype doesn't allow Java files

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I created a new Maven Project and selected the org.codehaus.mojo.arhcetypes ear-javaee6 archetype.  When I try to add a Java class to the project I get "Source folder is not a java project".

So we are not supposed to add Java classes to out .ear files now.  What are these guys thinking when they create a project for a .ear but don't allow for Java classes?

What archetype should I use for creating Java EE 6 .ear files?

Comment: +1 for solidarity (same issue). Gorram Eclipse is frustrating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wikipedia, EAR (file format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_%28file_format%29):

> EAR (Enterprise Archive) is a file format used by Java EE for
>   packaging one or more modules into a single archive [...]

Create an EJB (`ejb-javaee6` archetype) or WAR project (`webapp-javaee6` archetype for example) for your java codes and refer to it from the [Ear plugin configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_%28file_format%29) (and add as dependency too).